# Unable to fetch data from properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my current application I am having a properties file which has certain properties of student and I am writing a class with a main function to extract those properties and Iam using below code, but I am getting null values for all properties,I tried using getproperty() and it is working fine but I need to do this using @Value . Any solution?

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:sample.properties")
public class Test
{
  @Value("${student.name}")
  private String name;

 public void test()
 {
  System.out.println("name "+name);
 }
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
   Test t=new Test();
   t.test();
 }
```

I'm getting

name = null

Comment: Is this your properties file name "sample.properties" ?

Comment: yes< its my propery filename

Comment: You are creating a new instance yourself, rendering all those annotations useless.

Comment: So we can't write a main in the same class ?

Comment: You need to use spring Boot to detect this class, pull it from the context and use it (or construct a context yourself using this class and retrieve it and use it).

Comment: When you do `Test t=new Test();`, you are explicitly NOT using Spring, so all those Spring annotations are useless.   Instead, to run a Spring application, use `SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args);`, as shown in https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args); also giving null, it is not reading from that properties file, is there something i'm missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your test class,

```
@Configuration
public class Tester {
    @Value("${student.name}")
    private String name;
     
    public String getName(){
       return name;
    }
}
```

You should use application context provided by spring boot like this,

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(DemoApplication.class);
        ApplicationContext context = application.run(args);

        // you can get object of any class like this.
        Test testObj = context.getBean(Test.class);  
        System.out.println("Student Name : "+testObj.getName());
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.